# Mobile application with multiple languages ​without using Google API

Tags: php, android, ios

I want to implement multiple language in android and ios application but i don't use google api because it's paid

So suggest me to best way for translate whole application data or php api response in multiple languages

Comment: Your question isn't clear, do want the UI to support multiple languages?

Comment: Yes my application UI support multiple language. I want whole application data in multi languages eg. if i select Chinese language in phone then whole application data display in Chinese language

Comment: So you want data on the server to support multiple languages?

Comment: yes i want data on the server to support multiple languages

Comment: It appears that you are looking for service to translate the data on the server. That is off-topic for StackOverflow. From https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Answer (score 0):

first you need to check for all devices whether it supports particular language or not.

```
public static boolean isSupported(Context context, String text) {
        int w = 200, h = 80;

        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
        Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
        Bitmap orig = bitmap.copy(conf, false);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
        paint.setTextSize((int) (14 * scale));

        // draw text to the Canvas center
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
        int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2;
        int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height()) / 2;

        canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
        boolean res = !orig.sameAs(bitmap);
        orig.recycle();
        bitmap.recycle();
        return res;
}
```

then you can use different resources xml files.

```
res->values->strings.xml
```

add another `values` folder another language. like if you want to add gujarati support you can add `values-gu` folder and in that `strings.xml` with same name as default `strings.xml`.

your new xml file will be here

```
res->values-gu->strings.xml
```

you  can check it in details also. [Check here](https://lalitjadav007.blogspot.in/2017/06/android-multi-language-support.html)

**Now for api response** , save selected language and pass it with api calling and return result in particular language. In database you have to save all details in all languages. While retrieving data retrieve only for particular language.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, i already did this but for translation i have used google translate api it's too costly so i want alternate way of google translate api

Answer (score 0):

Use MS Azure API it is free for quite a few trips. I use it in one of my dynamic translation applications.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/translatorapi.aspx

It will cost when you start translating so many messages, but at that point you can afford to pay if you are having that many users.